# How to prevent table view from not selecting the cell when keyboard is up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard

I have an app where there is a search field on top nav bar. When the user taps on the search field, the keyboard comes up and the background is greyed out. However at this point if the user taps on a cell in the table view, then the keyboard goes away and the cell drills down to the next screen. .how do i prevent this? The only way I can think of is to check if the keyboaard is present and if so then just dismiss the keyboard and do nothing. Is there any other way around it?

I also have buttons in the tableview cell which also activates when it is tapped when the keyboard is up. So I guess I need a generic way of knowing if the keyboard is up and just dismiss and not do any action.

Answer (score 1):

Implement UITextViewDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate

Something like this:

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

          UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
              if ([theTextView isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != theTextView) {

                      [tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                      [textField resignFirstResponder];
              }
              [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        }

        - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

           [tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        }
```